# Cocoa webview textfield not accepting keyboard shortcuts

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, webview, shortcut

I have a webview under a window cocoa app for native Mac OS X app. However All works good but the keyboard shortcuts are not working, if I select any text inside the webview I cannot copy/paste using the keyboard shortcuts like: CMD + C (copy) and CMD + V (paste)

I have been trying to implement the following code into AppDelegate.m:
- (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)key
{
    return YES;

}

but It did not work, wondering if I'm missing some code there.

Any idea hint about how to implement PerformKeyEquivalent method to allow the default shortcuts of keyboard?

Thanks in advance.